# Java array counters

Tags: java, arrays, random, counter

I am practicing using The new Boston tutorials, however there is one program that I don't fully understand. The program is designed to count the frequency of a number occuring in each dice roll and storing the results in an array. The line I have trouble with is **++freq[1+newDice.nextInt(6)]**. I understand **[1+newDice.nextInt(6)]**; however how does the array know to increment each index by one each time the number occurs?

```
Random newDice = new Random ();

        int freq[] = new int [7];

        for(int i = 1; i<= 1000; i++)
        {
            ++freq[1+newDice.nextInt(6)];
        }

        System.out.println("Dice Number\tFrequency");
        for(int i = 1; i< freq.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"\t\t"+freq[i]);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is incrementing the value stored at that position in the array. It is not incrementing the array index.

It is equivalent to:

```
int index = 1+newDice.nextInt(6);
int f = freq[index];
++f;
freq[index] = f;
```

Comment: Thanks Graham for clarifying.